# TextView and ImageView do not top-align at the same level

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very simply horizontal `LinearLayout` with one `ImageView` and one `TextView` and both `layout_gravity` is set to `top`. Both views do indeed align at the top of the layout, but the `TextView` is always slightly lower, and to get to align with the `ImageView` I have to give it a negative `layout_marginTop`.

Am I missing something here?

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.67"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="This is some text\nwith several\nline breaks"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Result**
[image: Works fine in designer, but looks wrong in runtime]

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`for textview try with android:layout_height="match_parent" and set its `gravity` to top

Comment: The `TextView` needs to `wrap_content` because sometimes the text is larger than the image. The solution provided here however still does not make a difference.

Comment: did you try setting gravity to top

Comment: Yes, it stays at the same level.